# problema con método en la clase main de proyecto "ListaDeReproduccion"

Tags: java, array, metodos, main

Les dejo el código un poco mas resumido, ya que había formulado una pregunta con demasiado código.
En la opción 3 del menú de opciones se encuentra mi problema, la opción seria agregar una canción a la lista de reproducción. En dicha clase se encuentra un array con todas las canciones que el usuario puede elegir y agregar a su lista de reproducción,mi duda es como puedo hacer para mostrarle al usuario todas las canciones y que pueda elegir cuales agregar a su lista.

- Aquí esta la clase "ListaDeReproduccion",en donde cree el método agregarCancion para luego utilizarla en la clase main.

```java
public class ListaDeReproduccion {

    private String nombre;
    private Cancion canciones[];
    private final int CANTIDAD_MAXIMA_DE_CANCIONES = 1000;

    public ListaDeReproduccion(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        canciones = new Cancion[CANTIDAD_MAXIMA_DE_CANCIONES];

    }

    public boolean agregarCancion(Cancion nueva) {

        for (int i = 0; i < canciones.length; i++) {
            if (canciones[i] == null) {
                canciones[i] = nueva;
                return true;

            }

        }
        return false;

    }
```

- aqui la clase "Cancion".

```java
public class Cancion {

    private String nombre;
    private String genero;
    private long duracionEnSegundos;
    private String artista;

    public Cancion(String nombre, String genero, long duracionEnSegundos, String artista) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.duracionEnSegundos = duracionEnSegundos;
        this.artista = artista;

    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }

    public long getDuracionEnSegundos() {
        return duracionEnSegundos;
    }

    public String getArtista() {
        return artista;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.nombre + " - " + this.artista + " - " + this.genero + " - " + this.duracionEnSegundos;
    }

}
```

- Clase "Usuario". Muestro los metodos que hice

```java
public class Usuario {

    private String nombre;
    private int edad;
    private ListaDeReproduccion misListasDeReproduccion[];

    public Usuario() {
        this.nombre = "";
        this.edad = 0;
        this.misListasDeReproduccion = new ListaDeReproduccion[35];

    }

    public boolean agregarNuevaLista(String nombreDeLaLista) {

        for (int i = 0; i < misListasDeReproduccion.length; i++) {
            if (misListasDeReproduccion != null) {
                misListasDeReproduccion[i] = new ListaDeReproduccion(nombreDeLaLista);
                return true;

            }

        }

        return false;
    }

    public String verMisListasDeReproduccion() {

        String miLista = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < misListasDeReproduccion.length; i++) {
            if (misListasDeReproduccion[i] != null) {
                miLista += "[" + (i + 1) + "]" + misListasDeReproduccion[i].toString() + ",\n";
            }

        }

        return miLista;
    }

    public String reproducirLista(int numeroDeLista) {

        return misListasDeReproduccion[numeroDeLista].toString();

    }

    public ListaDeReproduccion[] getMisListasDeReproduccion() {
        return misListasDeReproduccion;
    }
```

- Y por ultimo la clase main "InterfazReproductor" en donde se encuentra mi problema.

```java
public class InterfazReproductor {

    private static final int GUARDAR_MIS_DATOS_PERSONALES = 1, CREAR_UNA_LISTA_DE_REPRODUCCION = 2,
            AGREGAR_CANCIONES_A_UNA_LISTA = 3, REPRODUCIR_UNA_LISTA = 4, VISUALIZAR_CANCIONES = 5, SALIR = 9;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("\t*Bienvenido al reproductor de la Unlam*");
        Usuario elUsuarioDeEsteDispositivo = new Usuario();
        Cancion cancionero[] = obtenerCancionesDisponibles();

        int opcionIngresada;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            mostrarMenu();
            opcionIngresada = teclado.nextInt();
            elUsuarioDeEsteDispositivo = determinarAccionArealizar(cancionero, elUsuarioDeEsteDispositivo,
                    opcionIngresada, teclado);

        } while (opcionIngresada != 9);

    }

    private static void mostrarMenu() {
        System.out.println("************************");
        System.out.println("Menu de opciones\n");
        System.out.println(GUARDAR_MIS_DATOS_PERSONALES + " - Guardar mis datos personales");
        System.out.println(CREAR_UNA_LISTA_DE_REPRODUCCION + " - Crear una lista de reproduccion ");
        System.out.println(AGREGAR_CANCIONES_A_UNA_LISTA + " - Agregar canciones a una lista");
        System.out.println(REPRODUCIR_UNA_LISTA + " - Reproducir una lista");
        System.out.println(VISUALIZAR_CANCIONES + " - Ver mi lista de reproduccion");
        System.out.println(SALIR + " - Salir");
        System.out.println("************************");
        System.out.print("Ingrese la opcion deseada: ");
    }
        public static Cancion[] obtenerCancionesDisponibles() {

        Cancion cancionero[] = { new Cancion("Latinoamerica", "Rock", 120, "Calle 13"),
                new Cancion("Dime mentiras", "Pop", 85, "Carla Morrison"),
                new Cancion("Antes y Despues", "Rock", 63, "Ciro y los Persas"),
                new Cancion("Ala Delta", "Rock", 50, "Divididos"),
                new Cancion("La Rueda Magica", "Rock", 63, "Fito Paez"),
                new Cancion("Moscas en la casa", "Latino", 94, "Shakira"),
                new Cancion("San Jaureche", "Rock", 122, "Los Piojos"),
                new Cancion("Come As You Are", "Rock", 86, "Nirvana"),
                new Cancion("Una Lady Como tu", "Desconocido", 45, "Manuel Turizo"),
                new Cancion("Smells Like Teen Spirit", "Rock", 93, "Nirvana"),
                new Cancion("Verte Reir", "Rock", 85, "No te va a gustar"),
                new Cancion("Ji Ji Ji", "Rock", 76, "Patricio Rey y sus redonditos de Ricota"),
                new Cancion("Una cervez", "Cumbia", 33, "Rafaga"),
                new Cancion("La leyenda del Hada", "Rock", 113, "Rata Blanca"),
                new Cancion("Me extraniaras", "Cuarteto ", 85, "Ulises Bueno"),
                new Cancion("Si te vas ", "Latino", 93, "Shakira"),
                new Cancion("Sea of Teeth", "Funk", 85, "Sparkehorse"),
                new Cancion("Hello Sunshine", "Chill Out", 76, "Super Furry Animals"),
                new Cancion("It's not the end of the world", "Chill Out", 90, "Super Furry Animals"),
                new Cancion("No se llama amor", "Rock", 83, "Turf"),
                new Cancion("Pasos al costado", "Rock", 93, "Turf"),
                new Cancion("November Rain", "Rock", 110, "Guns & Roses"),
                new Cancion("Way Back Into Love", "Movies", 90, "Hugh Grant & Drew Barrymore"),
                new Cancion("Auto Rojo", "Retro", 87, "Vilma Palma e Vampiros"),
                new Cancion("Bella", "Pop", 80, "Wolfine"),
                new Cancion("True to Myself", "Reagee", 120, "Ziggy Marley"),
                new Cancion("See Dem Fake Lead", "Reagee", 56, "Ziggy Marley"),
                new Cancion("Casi Nadie", "Rock", 116, "Los Caballeros de la Quema"),
                new Cancion("Sombra de Ti", "Pop", 110, "Shakira"),
                new Cancion("Don't Stop Me Now", "Rock", 116, "Queen"),
                new Cancion("Huelga de Princesas", "Rock", 110, "Los Caballeros de la Quema"), };

        return cancionero;
    }
        public static void agregarUnaCancion(Scanner teclado, Cancion[] cancionero, Usuario elUsuarioDeEsteDispositivo) {

        ListaDeReproduccion nueva;
        Cancion buscada;
        String nombre;

        System.out.println("Canciones disponibles: : ");
        listarCancionesDisponibles();

        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de la cancion que desea agregar: ");
        nombre = teclado.next();
        
        nueva = new ListaDeReproduccion(nombre);

        
    }
    private static void listarCancionesDisponibles() {

        Cancion cancionero[] = obtenerCancionesDisponibles();

        for (int i = 0; i < cancionero.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("" + (i + 1) + " - " + cancionero[i]);

        }
    }
```

En la clase main les muestro el menú de opciones disponible en el proyecto, el array "cancionero" que debo utilizar para mostrarle al usuario las canciones que puede elegir y, debajo de todo, el método `agregarCancion` que hice para utilizar en la opción 3 del menú. También otro método que creé para listar las canciones. Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo hago para que el usuario elija una canción de las que hay y se guarde a su lista de reproducción?

Comment: Supongo que has de listar las canciones al usuario y que eliga una por el número (índice). Con ese índice puedes fácilmente copiar la canción a la lista de reproducción de dicho usuario

Comment: exactamente,lo que si el usuario debería elegir por el nombre de la canción,ya que al método  agregarCancion de la clase ListaDeReproduccion se le pasa el parámetro (Canción nombre),las canciones las liste solo para enumerarlas solo por eso.Y creo que el método que hice en la clase main esta mal hecho y no puedo hacer que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

No te voy a resolver el ejercicio, pero te daré una guía:

- Tienes un objeto `Usuario` que tiene como propiedad una colección de `ListaDeReproducción`. No sé si tiene sentido que tenga varias listas, pero asumiendo que sea un requisito:
- Cuando un usuario quiera añadir una canción, necesitas preguntar dos cosas:

  - Qué canción quiere añadir: Podrías hacer que `cancionero` fuera una `ListaDeReproduccion`
    `Cancion encontrarCancionPorNombre(String nombre) {...}`
  - En qué lista de reproducción del usuario quieres añadirla, quizá con un método en Usuario que sea algo como:
    `usuario.encontrarLista(nombreLista);` que devuelva la lista deseada.
- Una vez que sepas dos cosas, podrás añadir la canción:
  `lista.agregarCancion(nuevaCancion)`

Comment: hola pablo,muchas gracias!! veré si puedo resolverlo de esa manera.

Answer (score 0):

Le hice unas modificaciones a tu clase **InterfazReproductor**.

```
public class InterfazReproductor {

   static Scanner teclado = new Scanner( System.in );
   private static final int GUARDAR_MIS_DATOS_PERSONALES = 1, CREAR_UNA_LISTA_DE_REPRODUCCION = 2,
           AGREGAR_CANCIONES_A_UNA_LISTA = 3, REPRODUCIR_UNA_LISTA = 4, VISUALIZAR_CANCIONES = 5, SALIR = 9;

   public static void main( String args[] ) {
      System.out.println( "\t*Bienvenido al reproductor de la Unlam*" );
      Usuario elUsuarioDeEsteDispositivo = new Usuario();
      int opcionIngresada;

      do {
         mostrarMenu();
         opcionIngresada = teclado.nextInt();
         switch( opcionIngresada ) {
            case 1: guardarDatos( elUsuarioDeEsteDispositivo );
               break;
            case 2: crearNuevaLista( elUsuarioDeEsteDispositivo );
               break;
            case 3: agregarUnaCancion( elUsuarioDeEsteDispositivo );
               break;
            case 4: reproducir( elUsuarioDeEsteDispositivo );
               break;
            case 5: listarCancionesDisponibles();
               break;
            case 9:
               break;
            default:
               System.out.println( "Por favor, ingresa un número válido" );
               break;
         }
      }
      while( opcionIngresada != 9 );
   }

   private static void mostrarMenu() {
      System.out.println( "************************" );
      System.out.println( "Menu de opciones\n" );
      System.out.println( GUARDAR_MIS_DATOS_PERSONALES + " - Guardar mis datos personales" );
      System.out.println( CREAR_UNA_LISTA_DE_REPRODUCCION + " - Crear una lista de reproduccion " );
      System.out.println( AGREGAR_CANCIONES_A_UNA_LISTA + " - Agregar canciones a una lista" );
      System.out.println( REPRODUCIR_UNA_LISTA + " - Reproducir una lista" );
      System.out.println( VISUALIZAR_CANCIONES + " - Ver mi lista de reproduccion" );
      System.out.println( SALIR + " - Salir" );
      System.out.println( "************************" );
      System.out.print( "Ingrese la opcion deseada: " );
   }  

   public static void agregarUnaCancion( Usuario elUsuarioDeEsteDispositivo ) {
      selecciona listaDeReproduccion nueva o existente;
      pedir nombre;
      System.out.println( "Canciones disponibles: : " );
      listarCancionesDisponibles();
      System.out.println( "Ingrese el nombre de la canción que desea agregar: " );
         // yo cambiaría nombre por número, es más fácil de implementar
      nombre = teclado.next();
      lista.agregar( cancionero[ i ] );
   }

   private static void crearUsuario() {
   
   }

   private static void crearNuevaLista() {
   
   }

   private static void reproducir() {
 
   }

   private static void listarCancionesDisponibles() {
      for( int i = 0; i < cancionero.length; i++ ) {
         System.out.println( "" + ( i + 1 ) + " - " + cancionero[ i ] );
      }
   } 
   
   static Cancion cancionero[] = {
      new Cancion( "Ala Delta", "Rock", 50, "Divididos" ),
      new Cancion( "Come As You Are", "Rock", 86, "Nirvana" ),
      new Cancion( "Smells Like Teen Spirit", "Rock", 93, "Nirvana" ),
      new Cancion( "Ji Ji Ji", "Rock", 76, "Patricio Rey y sus redonditos de Ricota" ),
      new Cancion( "La leyenda del Hada", "Rock", 113, "Rata Blanca" ),
      new Cancion( "November Rain", "Rock", 110, "Guns & Roses" ),
      new Cancion( "Don't Stop Me Now", "Rock", 116, "Queen" )
   };
}
```

Vamos por partes con los cambios:
**obtenerCancionesDisponibles**  se elimina, ya que es como pedir "alcansame eso que tengo en la mano".

En **listarCancionesDisponibles**, eliminamos **Cancion cancionero[] = obtenerCancionesDisponibles();**.

La linea **elUsuarioDeEsteDispositivo = determinarAccionArealizar( cancionero, elUsuarioDeEsteDispositivo, opcionIngresada, teclado );** se cambia por un switch, que llama a los métodos adecuados.

Por último, el método **agregarUnaCancion** no lo escribí como tal, pero te deje una suerte de guía, ya que considero que estás perfectamente capacitado para resolverlo.

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: genial,muchas gracias @MarcePuente !!!